# Are rake task arguments immutable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I want to modify the value of a task arguments (e.g. I want the argument to become a symbol). But it seems that the rake task arguments are immutable, is this correct?

```
  task :my_task,[:some_arg,:another_arg]  do |cmd,args|
    puts args[:some_arg].class
    args[:some_arg]=args[:some_arg].to_sym
    puts args[:some_arg].class
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at rake source here https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb we can examine, that method `[]` is overridden with:

```
# Find an argument value by name or index.
def [](index)
  lookup(index.to_sym)
end
```

So it is not possible to modify arguments that way.